# Printing a sentence involving a function

Tags: python

How can I print out the following sentence

> "The temperature is 30"

such that 30 is changeable? In other word, I wrote:

```
temp = 30 
print (The temperature is "+ repr(temp)")


print "The temperature is "+ repr (temp)"
```

But the system says syntax error.

What is a correct way of writing this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add the complete syntax error to your question. Without it we can only guess and the question might get closed as off-topic. Also: Are you sure this is BASIC? This looks an awful lot like Python to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note**: I am assuming you are writing a python program here, as your code does not look like basic code at all. The following has been tested using Python3 but might also work on Python2.

---

Your string delimiters are all over the place. Everything between the double quotes (`"`) will be treated as a string. As a quick fix you have to move double quotes like this:

```
print ("The temperature is "+ repr(temp))
```

Then `"The temperature is "` is a string and the result of `repr(temp)` is appended to it. Right now `"+ repr(temp)"` is interpreted as a string and `The temperature is` are treated as variables, which have not been defined. Hence the error.

For a little more detail, let's walk through this:

```
temp = 30 # sets an variable to 30 (integer)
text = "this is a string" + str(temp) # convert temp variable to string
                                      # append it to the string and store it
                                      # in the variable named text
print(text) # print the combined text
```

Note that `str` and `repr` do slightly different things:

- `str(x)` returns a readable string version of the variable `x`
- `repr(x)` returns an unambiguous string that is often used in interpreters etc.

In general you want to use `str` for tasks like this.
For more information about this take a look [at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python).

Comment: Thank you very much, that clarifies

Comment: @nerd If the answer answers your question please accept it so that others see that your question already has an answer that solved your problem.